# What are the magic variables in CLISP's REPL?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, clisp, interactive-mode

I have noticed that when I type an operator in REPL, it is often expanded into a value which has something to do with the input/output history.

Specifically I noticed that:

- `+`, `++` ... expand to previous inputs,
- `*`, `**` ... expand to previous outputs,
- `-` expand to the current input

There apparently are more (`/` expands to something but I haven't figured it out exactly).

I've tried browsing the clisp docs, but unsuccessfully.

My questions:

- What such magic REPL variables are also there? What do they do?
- Is there a way to access Nth input or output (like IPython's `In` and `Out` arrays)?

Comment: wow! I didn't know IPython's `In` and `Out` arrays, thanks!

Comment: It also has shorthands `_`, `__` ... which mean `Out[-1]`, `Out[-2]` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The REPL variables are documented in the [environment dictionary of the Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_enviro.htm) (search for "Variable"). The standard does not require holding any more of input/outputs than three, and I am not aware of any implementation that does it.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the other answer, these variables are documented in the ANSI Common Lisp standard.

In addition to that a Common Lisp implementation may have lots of other features. A full featured top-level with user interface is often called a 'Lisp listener'.

The CLISP implementation provides additional commands in the debugger. See [chapter 25](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes.html#environment) of its documentation.

LispWorks has some extensions in the REPL and also provides a [Listener](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/IDE-M/html/ide-m-377.htm#pgfId-853189). Here are some examples:

Interaction number 2, in the CL-USER package:

```
CL-USER 2 > (* 3 4)
12
```

The same, but we can omit the outer parentheses:

```
CL-USER 3 > * 3 4
12
```

Let's redo interaction 2:

```
CL-USER 4 > :redo 2
(* 3 4)
12
```

Let's redo interaction 2, but with division instead of multiplication:

```
CL-USER 5 > :use / * 2
(/ 3 4)
3/4
```

Other implementations with extensions like commands, output histories, or similar features are for example [Allegro CL](http://www.franz.com/support/documentation/8.2/doc/top-level.htm) and Clozure CL.

SLIME, which provides a Common Lisp development environment based on GNU Emacs, also provides an extended [REPL](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/REPL.html#REPL).